# Binding a .NET WinForms ListBox to a ConnectionStringSettingsCollection

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

I am trying to bind the ConnectionStringsSettingsCollection from my app.config file to a ListBox in my WinForms app.  For some reason, I can't seem to do it by the following method:

```
lstMyListBox.DataSource = GetConnectionStrings()
lstMyListBox.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

I am able to do it by iterating over the collection and adding each ConnectionStringSetting to lstMyListBox.Items:

```
For Each settings As ConnectionStringSettings In GetConnectionStrings()
    lstMyListBox.Items.Add(settings)
Next
lstMyListBox.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

Which works as far as modifying the individual items that are already in the collection, but I would like it if I remove something from the ListBox that it is removed from the underlying collection.  Is there something I can do different that will allow me to bind the ListBox directly to the ConnectionStringSettingsCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectionStringsSettingsCollection` doesn't implement `IList` or `IListSource`, so it can't be used as a `DataSource`. Instead you can bind a list of `ConnectionStringSettings`:

```
lstMyListBox.DataSource = GetConnectionStrings().Cast(Of ConnectionStringSettings).ToList()
lstMyListBox.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

However the `DisplayMember` doesn't seem to be taken into account, at least not for all items... but it works fine if you use "ConnectionString" as the `DisplayMember`. Not sure why...